# javascript within a script

Tags: javascript, syntax

I suppose this should be pretty simple, but I'm still learning to work with javascript. I have this function that I am using to pull up a form on the click of a button

```
function addEmployee() {
document.getElementById("add_employee")
.innerHTML="\
        <input name=\"new_emp_name\" value=\"Employee Name\" required/>\
        <input name=\"new_emp_idp\" value=\"Employee Number\" required/>\
        <select name=\"new_emp_status\" required>\
            <option value=\"0\">Manager</option>\
            <option value=\"1\" selected>Server</option>\
            <option value=\"2\">Bartender</option>\
            <option value=\"3\">Host</option>\
        </select>\
        <input type=\"submit\" value=\"Add employee\">\
";
}
```

which works fine. I want to add code for each input that will clear each field when it's clicked, such as...

```
onfocus="if(this.value == 'Employee Name') { this.value = ''; }"
```

so that each input would look something like

```
<input name=\"new_emp_name\" onfocus="if(this.value == 'Employee Name') { this.value = ''; }" value=\"Employee Name\" required/>\
```

but there's obviously something terribly wrong with my understanding of the syntax. Please advise! And thank you for your patience if I haven't searched for this question thoroughly.

Comment: What's with all the backslashes in the HTML?

Comment: the backslashes are because the input is in a string in javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use single quotes(') for the entire string and then you won't need to put the backslash before every double quote("). Check the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jGEj9/1/).

Your code is also correct. You need only to put backslashes in your `onfocus` attribute

```
onfocus=\"if(this.value == 'Employee Name') { this.value = ''; }\"
```

Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jGEj9/2/) as well. It is exactly your code with the escaped doble quote in the onfocus attribute

But I still prefer the answer provided above. It avoids the problems of escaping characters in String. This [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jGEj9/3/) incorporates that answer.

Note:
I am assuming that you are trying to put some sample text in the input which gets hidden whenever user focuses on the field. You can try using the html [placeholder](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/input/text) attribute to achieve the same behavior

`<input placeholder="Employee Name" otherattributes />`

Comment: Thank you! Placeholder was what I was looking for. Thanks for the escape info.

Answer (score 1):

It is advisable to do this instead: have a script with an non-standard type and take it's value. E.g., put this in your head tag:

```
<script type="x-random/x-html-string-thingy" id="newemployeehtml">
HTML HERE
</script>
```

and then in your script:

```
document.getElementById('add_employee').innerHTML=document.getElementById('newemployeehtml').innerHTML;
```

also, replace `HTML HERE` with the HTML for the new employee thingy (obviously), and you won't need backslashes

Comment: I like your answer but the problem was @cingenius was not escaping the double quotes in onfocus attribute.